# Orientation of cylindrical object while floating

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why does a body(especially cylindrical) when immersed completely in liquid (density of liquid >density of object) floats back up to the surface of water in horizontal Orientation regardless of it's initial orientation underliquid.is this because of less friction on surface of water and some air resistance? Centre of mass? Or torque? These are my some guesses of mine.

Comment: It depends on the shape. Cut a cylindrical disk out of a sheet of plywood. It will float with its axis vertical.

Comment: Here is a similar question that might give you a hint. Why will a pencil balanced on its end (cut the point off to make it a cylinder) fall over easily, but a coin balanced on a face not?

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that the horizontal configuration is stable, in terms of the center of pressure (red *x* below) is inline with the center of mass (cg marker below)

[image: fig1]

The center of pressure for buoyancy is the volumetric centroid of the displaced volume (blue shaded above). As you can see when there is a tilt to the cylinder the center of pressure is towards the sunken part causing a torque that will try to remove the tilt.

Comment: The picture is interesting because it suggests that the principle of Archimedes can be understood as an application of the theorem of the divergence. In this case, the volumetric integral of the weight of the fluid equals the surface integral of the fluid pressure on the boundaries of the solid.

Answer (score 5):

This is all about *stability* of equilibrium. If the cylinder is exactly vertical and the water calm, then there is a vertical position where the forces on it are balanced, so that is an equilibrium position and if you did not think about it any more you might think it could stay in that position. But it is an unstable equilibrium.

Stability, in this context, is about the way the forces act when the orientation is not right at the equilibrium, but near to it. When the angle is tilted off-vertical by a small amount, the combination of buoyancy and weight gives a net torque. There are two possibilities. Either this torque tends to restore the cylinder to the equilibrium, or it tends to rotate it further away. The first case is called stable equilibrium, the second case is called an unstable equilibrium.

Depending on the shape of the cylinder, either the vertical or the horizontal case may be unstable. If
the vertical situation for the cylinder is unstable, then the horizontal situation is stable. In this case if one were to bring the cylinder to vertical orientation and wait for the water to calm, and gently release the cylinder, it could in principle stay upright for some finite time. But it won't be long until a thermal fluctuation, or a larger effect, tips it to one side and then it will fall over.

In the case of releasing the cylinder from under water, during the motion as it rises and reaches the surface, any tiny imbalance on the forces on it will
make it rotate one way or another, and it will tend to find the more stable orientation. This is like a ball rolling along a series of hills and valleys: it will eventually settle at the bottom of a valley, not the top of a hill.

As the cylinder wobbles to and fro on its journey to the surface, responding to pressure and gravity, it sends out ripples and vortices which take up any angular momentum and energy which is released. It ends up horizontal because the net result of the forces of gravity and buoyancy is to tend to rotate it away from vertical and towards horizontal. (Buoyancy here is the net result of the pressure from all sides).

As I mentioned, you can also find shapes where the vertical orientation is stable. An example is a short flat cylinder, like a disk. It also depends on the relative density of the cylinder and the water (for a cylinder floating in water) I think. If it is mostly submerged then I have some intuition that it can be stable in the upright position, but I haven't done the calculation.

Comment: Your intuition is right. The stable orientation is the one that puts the center of mass at the lowest position. If a long thin rod has a density equal to, say, 0.75 times that of water, then a vertical orientation will put the center of mass well below the surface of the water, whereas the horizontal orientation will keep the center of mass near the surface. The vertical orientation is the stable one here.

Answer (score 0):

When the cylinder is long and thin, then it will float with its axis horizontal to the surface. When short and fat, with its axus vertical. Somewhere in between, it's motion will be chaotic which will be esoecially apparent if the water is in anyway moving, like on a lake or sea.

Of course, this depends on the composition of the cylinder. If its made of iron, it will sink no matter what its dimension is. Unless of course its hollow.

Comment: I wonder where the crossover point is between horizontal & vertical stability.