Why will a cylinder tend to freefall on its side?
In a video I saw about the U.S. military’s idea “Rods from God”, it said a uniform steel cylinder will tend to freefall in the air on its side if not corrected. It won't freefall vertically if left to its own forces.
If the center of mass is uniform, wouldn’t it just tumble in the sky as it fell? Resistance would be even on all sides of the cylinder, therefore even on the center of mass creating no net torque, right?

Relevant:  "Why do (short) strands of hair keep a horizontal position while falling?" and "Why does a falling bullet tend to land sideways?".

resistance of air would be equal only when roughly in horizontal position, else difference in angle and height produces unequal air resistance (and gravity pull)..

see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797089/orientation-of-cylindrical-object-while-floating

One-liner: Probabilistically, among all the ways to fall, those on the side one way or another are way more than those primarily vertically (*)(+).
(*) The difference gets larger and larger the taller the cylinder.
(+) All things being equal, cylinder will, in most cases, tend to fall on its side.
Another related answer: Falling on the side is a more stable configuration, among various perturbations, than falling primarily vertically (*)(+).

I will try to view this in a slightly different way. Let us first set the vertical as y-axis and horizontal as x-axis. Let us say your falling cylinder makes an angle $\theta$ with the y-axis such that it's axis lies in the first quadrant. While it is falling, the drag forces can rotate it in two ways, either towards the y axis or away from y axis (parallel to x axis).

If it gets rotated towards y axis, it's axis becomes along/parallel to y axis, then it's flat surface will be horizontal. But such a configuration will make it unstable due to slightly different drag forces acting on the flat horizontal surface. In that case, the cylinder axis tends to pass through being parallel to y axis (when it is momentarily parallel to y axis) and again becomes oblique to y axis eventually reaching a point in time when it will again be directed at $\theta$ with the y axis. But this situation of $\theta$ with the y axis is same as before when we started, only that it is in second quadrant this time. Therefore the only possible way then is to start rotation in the first place in such a way that it becomes parallel to x axis. This is the reason it is so stable with horizontal axis and hence fall with curved surface towards ground.
